# PHP store hours, closed dates

Tags: php, date, redirect, time

I've downloaded PHP store hours to show the weekday's opening hours, but now I would like to add some specific dates with different opening hours ( soon christmas you know! :-D ) but I really don't know how to do that so I was hoping for your help. E.g; I would like to change the opening hours for 25/12 and 1/1 ONLY, not all sundays.

Lots of thanks in advance!

```
// -------- PHP STORE HOURS ---------
// ---------- Version 1.1 -----------
// -------- BY CORY ETZKORN ---------
// -------- coryetzkorn.com ---------


// -------- EDIT FOLLOWING SECTION ONLY ---------

// Set your timezone (codes listed at http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
// Delete the following line if you've already defined a timezone elsewhere.
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm'); 

// Define daily open hours. Must be in 24-hour format, separated by dash.
$time_range_mon = '11:00-20:30';
$time_range_tue = '11:00-20:30';
$time_range_wed = '11:00-20:30';
$time_range_thu = '11:00-20:30';
$time_range_fri = '11:00-21:30';
$time_range_sat = '11:00-21:30';
$time_range_sun = '12:00-19:30';


// OPTIONAL: Output current day's open hours 
$echo_daily_hours = false; // Switch to FALSE to hide numerical display of current hours
$time_output = 'g a'; // Enter custom time output format (options listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
$time_separator = ' - '; // Choose how to indicate range (i.e XX - XX, XX to XX, XX until XX)

// -------- END EDITING -------- 

// Gets current day of week
$status_today = date("D"); 

// Gets current time of day in 00:00 format
$current_time = date("G:i");
// Makes current time of day computer-readable
$current_time_x = strtotime($current_time);

// Builds an array, assigning user-defined time ranges to each day of week
$all_days = array("Mon" => $time_range_mon, "Tue" => $time_range_tue, "Wed" => $time_range_wed, "Thu" => $time_range_thu, "Fri" => $time_range_fri, "Sat" => $time_range_sat, "Sun" => $time_range_sun);
foreach ($all_days as &$each_day) {
    $each_day = explode("-", $each_day);
    $each_day[0] = strtotime($each_day[0]);
    $each_day[1] = strtotime($each_day[1]);
}

// Defines array of possible days of week
$week_days = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");

// Compares current day of week to possible days of week and determines open vs closed output based on current day and time.
foreach ($week_days as &$each_week_day) {
        if ($status_today == $each_week_day) {
        echo '';
        if (($all_days[$each_week_day][0] <= $current_time_x) && ($all_days[$each_week_day][1] >= $current_time_x)) {

        } else {
        header( 'Location: http://www.bristolhotel.com/pizzeria/offlinepizza.php' ) ;
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: This is not a site for getting people to do your work for you.

Comment: you say you want to change the opening hours for them 2 dates but you dont say to what, are you closed all day on them dates?

Comment: I've since updated my PHP Store Hours plugin to allow for exception dates and more robust open / closed messages. Cheers!

http://coryetzkorn.com/blog/php-store-hours/

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Adjust `$time_range_christmas` and `$time_range_newyears` with your appropriate hours.

```
// -------- PHP STORE HOURS ---------
// ---------- Version 1.1 -----------
// -------- BY CORY ETZKORN ---------
// -------- coryetzkorn.com ---------


// -------- EDIT FOLLOWING SECTION ONLY ---------

// Set your timezone (codes listed at http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
// Delete the following line if you've already defined a timezone elsewhere.
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm'); 

// Define daily open hours. Must be in 24-hour format, separated by dash.
$time_range_mon = '11:00-20:30';
$time_range_tue = '11:00-20:30';
$time_range_wed = '11:00-20:30';
$time_range_thu = '11:00-20:30';
$time_range_fri = '11:00-21:30';
$time_range_sat = '11:00-21:30';
$time_range_sun = '12:00-19:30';
$time_range_christmas = '12:00-14:30';
$time_range_newyears = '12:00-14:30';


// OPTIONAL: Output current day's open hours 
$echo_daily_hours = false; // Switch to FALSE to hide numerical display of current hours
$time_output = 'g a'; // Enter custom time output format (options listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
$time_separator = ' - '; // Choose how to indicate range (i.e XX - XX, XX to XX, XX until XX)

// -------- END EDITING -------- 

// Gets current day of week
$status_today = date("D"); 

$todays_date = date("d M");
if ($todays_date == "25 Dec"){
    $status_today = "Christmas";
}
if ($todays_date == "1 Jan"){
    $status_today = "NewYears";
}



// Gets current time of day in 00:00 format
$current_time = date("G:i");
// Makes current time of day computer-readable
$current_time_x = strtotime($current_time);

// Builds an array, assigning user-defined time ranges to each day of week
$all_days = array("Mon" => $time_range_mon, "Tue" => $time_range_tue, "Wed" => $time_range_wed, "Thu" => $time_range_thu, "Fri" => $time_range_fri, "Sat" => $time_range_sat, "Sun" => $time_range_sun, "Christmas" => $time_range_christmas, "NewYears" => $time_range_newyears);
foreach ($all_days as &$each_day) {
    $each_day = explode("-", $each_day);
    $each_day[0] = strtotime($each_day[0]);
    $each_day[1] = strtotime($each_day[1]);
}

// Defines array of possible days of week
$week_days = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun", "Christmas", "NewYears");

// Compares current day of week to possible days of week and determines open vs closed output based on current day and time.
foreach ($week_days as &$each_week_day) {
        if ($status_today == $each_week_day) {
        echo '';
        if (($all_days[$each_week_day][0] <= $current_time_x) && ($all_days[$each_week_day][1] >= $current_time_x)) {
        } else {
            header( 'Location: http://www.bristolhotel.com/pizzeria/offlinepizza.php' ) ;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach here. Notice the rewriting of the script to use an array for time_range and then merging the array with differing times. Cleaner configuration in my opinion.

```
// -------- PHP STORE HOURS ---------
// ---------- Version 1.1 -----------
// -------- BY CORY ETZKORN ---------
// -------- coryetzkorn.com ---------


// -------- EDIT FOLLOWING SECTION ONLY ---------

// Set your timezone (codes listed at http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
// Delete the following line if you've already defined a timezone elsewhere.
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm'); 

// Define daily open hours. Must be in 24-hour format, separated by dash.
$time_range = array(
    'mon' => '11:00-20:30',
    'tue' => '11:00-20:30',
    'wed' => '11:00-20:30',
    'thu' => '11:00-20:30',
    'fri' => '11:00-21:30',
    'sat' => '11:00-21:30',
    'sun' => '12:00-19:30',
);

$diff_times = array(
    '2011-51' = array( // Index is Y-W (Year (4 digits)-ISO week number)
        'sat' => '11:00-15:00' // 2011-12-24
    ),
    '2011-52' = array(
        'sun' => '00:00-00:00' // 2011-12-25
    ),
);

// OPTIONAL: Output current day's open hours 
$echo_daily_hours = false; // Switch to FALSE to hide numerical display of current hours
$time_output = 'g a'; // Enter custom time output format (options listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
$time_separator = ' - '; // Choose how to indicate range (i.e XX - XX, XX to XX, XX until XX)

// -------- END EDITING -------- 

// Gets current day of week
$status_today = date("D"); 

// Gets current ISO week number (starting with monday)
$status_this_week = date("Y-W");
// If we have special opening hours, they are merged into the time range array
if (array_key_exists($status_this_week, $diff_times)) array_merge($time_range, $diff_times[$status_this_week]);

// Gets current time of day in 00:00 format
$current_time = date("G:i");
// Makes current time of day computer-readable
$current_time_x = strtotime($current_time);

// Builds an array, assigning user-defined time ranges to each day of week
$all_days = array("Mon" => $time_range['mon'], "Tue" => $time_range['tue'], "Wed" => $time_range['wed'], "Thu" => $time_range['thu'], "Fri" => $time_range['fri'], "Sat" => $time_range['sat'], "Sun" => $time_range['sun']);
foreach ($all_days as &$each_day) {
    $each_day = explode("-", $each_day);
    $each_day[0] = strtotime($each_day[0]);
    $each_day[1] = strtotime($each_day[1]);
}

// Defines array of possible days of week
$week_days = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");

// Compares current day of week to possible days of week and determines open vs closed output based on current day and time.
foreach ($week_days as &$each_week_day) {
        if ($status_today == $each_week_day) {
        echo '';
        if (($all_days[$each_week_day][0] <= $current_time_x) && ($all_days[$each_week_day][1] >= $current_time_x)) {

        } else {
        header( 'Location: http://www.bristolhotel.com/pizzeria/offlinepizza.php' ) ;
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Noticed you wanted 25/12 and 1/1, but you get the idea, just change the `$diff_time` array

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate your help! Yeah, I understand what you mean. Merry christmas to you! :) Thanks once again!

Comment: And a merry xmas/yule and a happy new year to you! ;)