# PHP day and time comparison

Tags: php, html

Hi I am quite new to PHP and Stackoverflow. I'd like help figuring out how to tell if today's date and time is between a predefined set of days and times. I would use the result to output "Shop closed" or "Shop opened".

Comment: Mate, you need to post some code that you've tried before the wolves get here!

Comment: How about a google search? Gave me this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521707/php-store-hours-closed-dates

Comment: Listen to them: the children of the night. What sweet music they make

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show a minimum of effort

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to handle the dates (and times if you need to) as they are comparable and you don't have to muck with converting to timestamps to do the comparisons.

```
$start = new DateTime('2014-01-01');
$end   = new DateTime('2014-04-01');
$now   = new DateTime();

if ($now > $start && $now < $end) {
    // open
}
else {
    // closed
}
```